# Strange BJT configuration, working as a diode?

Tags: bjt

I was looking at an old schematic and I came across this strange circuit for low voltage detection section of a larger circuit (not shown). The operation of circuit is straightforward, Q1 is normally conducting and the voltage divider R2/R3 set a threshold voltage, above which, Q2 conducts. When Q2 is normally conducting, the Q3 is off due to the voltage divider R1/R5. Upon depletion of power source,R2/R3 can no longer provide the base voltage for Q2 and it turns off. The Q3 turns on and discharges C2 to provide a pulse.
Does anyone know why Q1 is used in this configuration without the emitter connected to anywhere?

[image]

Comment: It might have been used to save having to use an extra part type. When getting PCBs assembled, each part you use adds overhead, so if you can use a kind of transistor you're already using a bunch of, instead of a kind of diode you're not, that saves money.

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is just a diode.

There are so many clever but inefficient design choices here, I wouldn't spend much time on it.

The person obviously doesn't know how to make a power on reset even with a miswired pot  and 3 transistors, one of which is experimental.

Pulse period is about 1x~2x RC or 32 ms

Comment: The pot was my mistake, it's corrected now.

Comment: Diode are only a penny in volume , there many ways to create a POR. This is very obsolete.